Python/Pandas: Shuffle data within one column within multiple grouped pandas columns
I am trying to shuffle data within the same group in a dataframe (grouping 4 columns together) using pandas and numpy as shown below.
The grouped columns are ID, values, source, type, and function. I have copied the same values from the 'value' column into the 'values_new_column' and would like to shuffle within this new column 'values_new_column' (image attached).
So far, I have written this code:
pdf1["values_new_column"] = pdf1.groupby("values")['source','type', 'function', 'ID'].transform(np.random.permutation)

The error says that the current library says that indexing with multiple keys will be deprecated and has asked me to use a list instead. Is there any way I can shuffle the records within one column inside multiple grouped pandas columns?
Expected output:


The warning is telling you to do this: [['source','type', 'function', 'ID']] for you slicing.

I did try converting it to a list but it throws a ValueError: Expected a 1D array, got an array with shape (352446, 4)

Your approach is correct, but you need to pay attention to the arguments that you are passing to the groupby method. This is the correct way to permutate values in the selected groups:
df['new_values'] = df.groupby(['source','type', 'function', 'ID'])['values'].transform(np.random.permutation)


Glad this this helps. Don't forget to upvote or mark answer as a solution. thx.

Yes I will upvote!
